# XNA 3d model mesh.draw() throws TextureCoordinate0 is missing error

Tags: xna, 3d-meshes, fbx

I've downloaded a bunch of 3d models from turbosquid.com. The majority of the one's I've downloaded are simply .fbx files. When I load the model into my game and run it, the following error is thrown in `mesh.draw()`:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll

Additional information: The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. TextureCoordinate0 is missing.
```

All the answers I've found online seem to tell people to reexport the model, or change something in the shader. I don't have access to these, just the fbx file. What can I do?

Comment: It sounds like the content importer is discarding the texture coordinate component for the mesh vertices. Do you happen to have the source for the content importer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm kind of new to this. I'm calling `Content.Load<Model>(@"Models\model")` to load it...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to adding textures to your model, you can stop the default `BasicEffect` from looking for them when drawing.

```
//foreach BasicEffect basicEffect in model.mesh[n].effects ....

basicEffect.TexturesEnabled = false;

//begin effect pass...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is missing the Texture Coordinates. You need to unwrap the model in a 3D modeling program, then export it.

Comment: Often the models come with no UV wrapping, basically.  If you look when you're browsing and downloading the models they will often say if they have textures or UV mapping.  IF they don't, you'll have to  import it into something yourself and do the texture mapping.